# How to make workspace switcher work properly?

Tags: unity, workspaces

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and the workspace switcher button in the launcher has stopped working. Not sure how or when this happened, or what I might have done to cause this problem. But when I click it, it does nothing and I cannot remove or move it either.

All the other buttons in the launcher seem to work correctly and I can move them around freely.

I can still use the keyboard shortcut keys to switch from one workspace to another. So, it is not that I only have one workspace.

So, how to make the workspace switcher work?

Comment: The workspace switcher in unity (3d) is provided by the compiz plugin "expo". If you hold down the super button (aka windows key) & then press s does it work? If not then possibly the  expo plugin has been disabled

Comment: thanks doug,  that fixed it,  don't remember turning it off.  But then again  Thank You

Comment: @doug - please convert your comment to an answer so that we can vote on this and close it!  Well done for solving it.

Comment: @doug I agree with fossfreedom convert this to an answer and you've got a +1 from me!

Answer (score 6):

> The workspace switcher in unity (3d) is provided by the compiz plugin "expo". If you hold down the super button (aka windows key) & then press s does it work? If not then possibly the expo plugin has been disabled